# How to say "person who is consistent" (in romaji) ? Is it a Japanese principle?

Tags: translation, culture

I have seen a documentary about a mangaka who would draw her own manga from start to finish and the documentary described that she was applying a Japanese principle of doing things alone, at your own pace, from start to finish. It was described as a principle of responsibility and integrity and it was contrasted to the way in western productions usually creating something is done by several people with different skills, whereas in Japan when you do everything yourself, your spirit is reflected throughout your work and has therefore more soul and harmony.

The documentary described this principle as a principle of integrity, of responsibility, a person should take responsibility and work through things on their own. The mangaka kept saying she wanted to be a person of integrity because of this principle.

The principle in Japanese sounded like "Suji yo konsu" meaning a person who is consistent, but since I don't speak Japanese at all (I only begin), I can't find which principle it is. Do you know which principle it is and how to write it in romaji? I have looked in Google I can't find any information on the documentary or on this principle. I would really like to learn more about this principle if only I knew how it is called in Japan.

Thanks.

--
An answer from a Japanese speaker who will recognize this principle and give the word or phrase that describes this principle even if it doesn't sound like what I think I have heard is also acceptable. I suspect it is something the Japanese know and live by so maybe there is a common word for it and I might have misheard. My interest is to know more about this principle of responsibility/integrity/own path/consistency to do something alone from start to finish. From the documentary there is a strong emphasis in doing things alone in this principle.

Comment: (1) Which one does this word/phrase refer to -- the idea or the person?  I have a phrase in mind that starts exactly with "suji".  (2) How would you know it if someone gave you the correct (or incorrect) answer?

Comment: It refers to the idea but the documentary translated it as "person who is consistent". I will know if it's the answer I'm looking for if when I search for it on the Internet, it details the principle I have described. I don't know if it's a principle well known in Japan, in education or in the moral, but for example I expect it to be like when I search for "ganbaru" which has a wikipedia page about the principle it stands for. I think I don't have the correct keyword to search for it. "Shoshi kantetsu" from 1st answer seems very close but there is still not much info on the web about it.

Comment: The phrase I was thinking of is "Suji o toosu", which is a verb phrase.

Comment: And what does it mean (I can't find it on Google)? Could you please provide kanji too?

Comment: 筋を通す.  It means "to stick to one's principles", "to go through the proper channels", etc.

Comment: 筋を通す seems like a likely candidate, but I'm concerned that there's no real way to know the correct answer to this question for sure

Comment: I will take both answers. I asked in case it is a well known principle in Japanese like "ganbaru" that would be obvious to a Japanese. I will try to find this documentary and provide the link back here to confirm. (it was a ANA program called IZA NOW on the plane about Carolin Eckhardt so it is very hard to find online).Thanks!

Comment: @非回答者:  [Comments are not for answers](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/593/78).

Answer (score 2):

This is a guess, but it might be 初志貫徹{しょしかんてつ}, or "shoshi kantetsu." It is a 四字熟語 compound that refers to having an idea/feeling/will and seeing it through to completion.

http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/idiom/%E5%88%9D%E5%BF%97%E8%B2%AB%E5%BE%B9/m0u/

Answer (score 2):

This phrase, 筋を通す, seems to actually show up in [dictionaries](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/118188/m0u/%E3%81%99%E3%81%98%E3%82%92%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8A%E3%81%99/) as a unit on a regular basis.

Unfortunately it doesn't usually show up in the japanese->english section, and when it does the entry is [incomplete](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E7%AD%8B%E3%82%92%E9%80%9A%E3%81%99).  So I'll supplement the links given here with a couple examples from the Genius and O-Lex Japanese-English dictionaries:

> 彼は最後まで**筋を通した。**
> *He stuck to his principles* to the end.
>
> 私は**筋を通さない**と気が済まない。
> I feel guilty if I *don't go through proper channels.*

As [非回答者](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/4032/%e9%9d%9e%e5%9b%9e%e7%ad%94%e8%80%85) said in the comments, the phrase has a general meaning of "following through" with principles or procedures (personal, official or cultural).